# How to use a function in a group_by statement?

Tags: r, tidyverse

What I have done so far:

- For every observation in my data.frame there is an observed value (`value`) and a list of simulated values (`simulations`).
- For every simulation I have calculated the average (i.e. the average of all n-th elements of the lists with simulated values).
- The average `value` in the data is compared to the averages of the simulations to calculate a percentile.

What I am trying to achieve:

- The same as what I have done so far, but after grouping by one of the group variables (`group_var1` and `group_var2`).
- The desired outcome would be a data.frame with the group_by variable, the group, the average value of this group, and the percentile of this value in relation to the simulated value. See the code for details

The simplified code:

```
# Initializing data.frame
df <- data.frame(group_var1 = c(rep("A", 5), rep("B", 5)),
                 group_var2 = c(rep(c("C", "D"), 5)),
                 value = runif(10)) 

# Simulating 100 values for every observation
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(simulations = list(runif(100)))

# Calculate average value per simulation (n-th element of the list)
avg_simulation <- rowMeans(simplify2array(df$simulations))

# Define function to calculate the percentile
percentile <- ecdf(avg_simulation)

# Calculating the percentile of the average value over the entire df
df_total <- df %>% 
  summarize(mean_value = mean(value)) %>% 
  mutate(simulation_percentile = percentile(mean_value))

# Desired output after grouping by the group variables (one at a time)
data.frame(risk_factor = c("group_var1", "group_var1", "group_var2", "group_var2"),
           risk_class = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), 
           mean_value = c(0.551, 0.213, 0.763, 0.532),
           simulation_percentile = c(0.534, 0.245, 0.780, 0.561))
```

I am struggling to get to the desired output.

Comment: Take a look at `group_map`.

Comment: Please use `set.seed` for reproducibility.  Try `df %>% pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('group'), names_to = 'risk_factor', values_to = 'risk_class') %>% group_by(risk_factor, risk_class) %>% summarise(mean_value = mean(value), percentile = list(ecdf(reduce(simulations, `+`)/length(simulations))), .groups = 'drop' ) %>% mutate(simulation_percentile = percentile(mean_value))`